# How can I go back to Previous layout by click on back button of mobile?

Tags: button, layout, android-studio

Hey I have added different layouts and they are working properly .
But I want that when we move from layout 1 to layout 2 ...
Then by clicking back button I want to go back layout 1.

How can i do it efficiently and effectively?

Comment: It does what you want by default normally, no? Can you explain more in details your need?

Comment: can we do it normaly.. i mean no code (just click mobile back button)

Comment: yes, I thought by clicking on back button, the app went to the last activity

Comment: If you want to change the default action of the back button, add this in the activity : public void onBackPressed(){ //actions } And put the actions you want instead of the comments

Comment: ok thank you so much :)

Comment: If it's what you expected, I write an answer to repeat my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose what action do when the back button is clicked, on each activity, just by adding this code in the activity you want :

```
public void onBackPressed(){ 
     //actions 
}
```